# Comma seperate an XML field query

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I am looking for a solution to get multiple values out of an XML field with a comma delimiter.

For example: I have a table which is a pin and an XML field.

```
1,<item>Number One</item><item>Number Two</item><item>Number Three</item>
```

The result I would like to see is:

```
1, Number One, Number Two, Number Three
```

With the following code, I can get the result of:

```
1, Number One Number Two Number Three
```

Using the following query:

```
SELECT 
    t.pin,
    t.items.query('for $I in items return string($I)').value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')  AS 'items'
FROM
    table
```

Due to the space between the item descriptions, I can't do a 'replace' on the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check it out.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xmldata)
VALUES
(N'<item>Number One</item><item>Number Two</item><item>Number Three</item>')
, (N'<item>Number One_2</item><item>Number Two_2</item><item>Number Three_2</item>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = ',';

SELECT ID, xmldata
    , xmldata.query('for $i in /item
        (: Node Comparison Operator - is :)
        return if ($i is (/item[last()])[1]) then string($i/text()[1])
                else concat($i, sql:variable("@separator"))')
    .value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS [Comma_separated_list]
FROM @tbl;
```

> Output

```
+----+--------------------------------------------+
| ID |            Comma_separated_list            |
+----+--------------------------------------------+
|  1 | Number One, Number Two, Number Three       |
|  2 | Number One_2, Number Two_2, Number Three_2 |
+----+--------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: This method is perfect, thanks for taking the time. It also takes into account the formatting of the string which is a very nice touch.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT 
    t.pin,
    STUFF(@xml.query('for $I in /item return concat('','', $I)').value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')   AS 'items'
FROM
    table
```

Comment: @GavCheal Nice pun. glad it works. Don't forget to mark the question answered, thanks